# How is this Intel Xeon mov instruction corrupting my application's memory?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86-64, compiler-bug, stack-corruption

I have an application built with gcc v7.3.0 and executing on an `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1220 v6` chip that corrupts stack memory deterministically and gets a SEGV due to executing a `mov` instruction.  I ran `valgrind` and no memory corruption was reported.

I have a `struct SolutionPattern` on the stack and its member variable, of type `const float * const &`, is getting clobbered when I begin calling the member function, `inline void RoleToEquation(float threshold)`.  In `GDB`, when enetring the member function, the forth instruction, `mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)`, causes the corruption as shown in the debugger:

```
Dump of assembler code for function SolutionPattern::RoleToEquation(float):
   0x00007fff9556b684 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00007fff9556b685 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00007fff9556b688 <+4>: sub    $0x20,%rsp
=> 0x00007fff9556b68c <+8>: mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x00007fff9556b690 <+12>:    movss  %xmm0,-0x1c(%rbp)
   0x00007fff9556b695 <+17>:    mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007fff9556b699 <+21>:    pxor   %xmm0,%xmm0
   0x00007fff9556b69d <+25>:    movss  %xmm0,0x88(%rax)
   0x00007fff9556b6a5 <+33>:    mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
   [...]
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) si
Hardware watchpoint 99: *$285

Old value = (const float * const) 0x7fffafb6087a <fflush+106>
New value = (const float * const) 0x7fffffff9ac0
0x00007fff9556b690 in SolutionPattern::RoleToEquation (this=0x7fffffff9ac0, threshold=4.59163468e-41) at calculate_edge.h:250
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function SolutionPattern::RoleToEquation(float):
   0x00007fff9556b684 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00007fff9556b685 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00007fff9556b688 <+4>: sub    $0x20,%rsp
   0x00007fff9556b68c <+8>: mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)
=> 0x00007fff9556b690 <+12>:    movss  %xmm0,-0x1c(%rbp)
   0x00007fff9556b695 <+17>:    mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007fff9556b699 <+21>:    pxor   %xmm0,%xmm0
   0x00007fff9556b69d <+25>:    movss  %xmm0,0x88(%rax)
   0x00007fff9556b6a5 <+33>:    mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
   [...]
End of assembler dump.
```

The member function source code begins like this:

```
inline void RoleToEquation(float threshold) {
    A = B = 0.f;
    C = threshold;
    D = E = 0.f;
    F = threshold;

    [...]
}
```

`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, and `F` are `float` member variables of the struct that occur several member variables after the memory that is being corrupted.

I don't fully understand the disassembly, but it appears that the function setup is still being run and the setting of `A` and `B` to `0.f` has not started yet.  I notice in the debugger that the argument `threshold` is  uninitialized until the fifth instruction, `movss`, executes.  How does the code to set up the argument variable `threshold` on the stack cause the struct to be corrupted that is located in the calling frame's stack memory?

What is likely going on here and how can I go about figuring out the source of this corruption.  Does the disassembly look proper?  Does this look like a compiler bug?  Note, only the debug build crashes, optimized build does not crash.  What is being performed by the first four instructions of this member function?  Is it improperly setting up the frame for the new function being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)` is just spilling the first function arg.  (The `this` pointer since this is a member function.)

It's not "corrupting" anything, you just compiled with optimization disabled so *everything* gets spilled to memory between C++ statements, including all the function args (implicit and explicit) on function entry.

`-0x18(%rbp)` is inside the `0x20` bytes of this function's own stack frame, reserved with `sub  $0x20,%rsp` (after `mov %rsp, %rbp` set the frame pointer to point to the qword below the return address).

> How does the code to set up the argument variable threshold on the stack cause the struct to be corrupted that is located in the calling frame's stack memory?

**It doesn't. `movss  %xmm0,-0x1c(%rbp)` also stores inside this function's own stack frame**.  That's a 4-byte store right below the spilled `this` pointer.  (These are negative offsets, and `0x1c - 0x18` = 4 = the width of the store.)

---

**If you found this by setting a HW watchpoint**, probably that was on the address of a local.  **The function containing that local has returned, and now that stack memory is being reused** as the stack frame for a different invocation of a different function.

Comment: The HW watchpoint is on a member of the `struct SolutionPattern` that is still on the stack in a parent frame, hence the memory corruption.  I'm thinking it is a bug in the compiler, perhaps the instance of `struct SolutionPattern` got located incorrectly on the stack by the compiler?  How can I check whether is is properly located on the stack?

Comment: @WilliamKF: by looking at the asm for the calling function.  Your question isn't a [mcve] because it doesn't include enough source to reproduce it, or asm for the caller.  Did it put the struct in the red zone (below RSP) before making a function call?  That would be a huge bug.  Did you use inline asm to make the function call so the compiler didn't know about it?